# Find extremizers using Lagrange multipliers

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

Using Lagrange multipliers,

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{extremize} & x + y\\ \text{subject to} & x^{2} + y^{2} \leq 5\\ & x \geq 0\end{array}$$

Graphically, it comes that the maximiser is $(\sqrt{5}, 0)$, but the minimizer is unclear. How to find it? How should Lagrange multiplier looks like?

Comment: Keep in mind that the region in question has an "edge", namely the points $x=0$ and $y\in (-\sqrt 5, \sqrt 5)$.  Derivative style tests won't work well on edges (such tests itend to imagine that there is  open neighborhoods around the points you are testing).  Therefore you have to handle the edge separately.

Comment: Lagrange multipliers and inequality constraints do not mix that well.

Answer (score 1):

For this simple problem you don't need Lagrange multipliers. Instead draw a figure.

The feasible domain $B$ is a right half disc of radius $\sqrt{5}$. The objective function has level lines $x+y=c$, which are lines descending with slope $45^\circ$. When $c$ gets larger the line is translated in  direction north-east. Now find out which is the most south-west such line meeting a point of $B$, and which is the most north-east such line meeting a point of $B$.

Note that one of the two points would not be found using Lagrange multipliers.